# router navigate with angular 7

Tags: angular, navigation

I have a question about navigation with angular 
somewhere in my code i have

```
this.router.navigate([12345678 + '/data']);
```

in my app-routing.module

```
    path: ':nossnbr/data',
    component: DataComponent,
  },
```

in my component DataComponent (in NgOnInit)

```
  ngOnInit() {
     this.routerSubscription = this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe(params => {
        // ....   do something
     });

  }
```

the navigate (this.router.navigate([12345678 + '/data']);) does not work. Nothing is happening , we do not go through the subscription

On the other hand if I type directly the url(localhost:4200/12345678/data) in the browser, there, it passes in the subscription

what is the difference between the 2 calls? Why it does not go through subscription when I use navigate ?

Comment: Try : `this.router.navigate([12345678 + '/data'], {relativeTo: this.route})`

Comment: Try `this.router.navigate(['12345678','data']);`

Comment: If your are defining route in feature or shared module refer my answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Best Practice**

You need to also define module name along with route.If routing is applied in root module only then module name is not required in route but when in different module route is navigate by defining module name where we need routing followed by route.

For example :
There are 2 modules: app and home module, we have defined one route in home routing module i.e /dashboard.

In root/app routing module define module routing like:

```
 path: 'home-module',
  loadChildren: () => import('./home/home.module').then(m => 
  m.HomeModule)
 },
```

In home module's component's .ts we will define routing like:

```
this._router.navigate(['./home-module/dashboard/']);
```

Answer (score 0):

What is your url at the point, when you navigate away with the router?

If its not *localhost:4200* then you need to edit the navigatie-url to:

```
this.router.navigate([12345678, 'data'])
```

Comment: when i use this.router.navigate([12345678, 'data']) , I have an error
core.js:1673 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: '12978696data'

Comment: Try: `this.router.navigate([12345678], '/data')`